# Why were AT-AT walkers armour able to mitigate T-47 laser damage when walking?

Tags: star-wars

When the battle of Hoth begun and Luke Skywalker leads his T-47 into battle shooting at the AT-AT walkers, he claims "that armour is too strong for blasters", yet moments later an AT-AT comes crashing down and a T-47 flies past, shooting it and the AT-AT explodes.

Was there an explanation as to why, first of all, Luke Skywalker's claim that the AT-AT armour is too strong for the T-47 lasers and secondly what difference did it make when the AT-AT had fallen down that rendered the armour mitigated so the T-47 could finally blow them up?

Looking for only canon answers please.

Comment: Only canon answers, or only cannon answers?

Comment: no pun or typo was to be intended... canon, as in G-canon etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Wookieepedia - [All Terrain Armored Transport](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Armored_Transport):

> The most vulnerable part of the walker was a weak point found at its flexible neck, which was susceptible to lighter blaster barrages.

Falling down put the walker in a position where the vulnerable spot on the neck was exposed, making it an easy, stationary target.

Comment: I am sorry but I'm downvoting this. Wookiepedia is NOT canon, so unless this specific quote has a cite/reference to an EU book, it sounds to me merely as a Wiki author writing up **a justification of what he sees in the movie**. It's a common occurence on Wookiepedia, sadly. Mind you, the explanation DOES make common sense, just no evidence that the explanation itself is canon.

Comment: @DVK That's reasonable.  There is a short story about Imperial Officer training that talks about AT-AT weaknesses, but all of those books are at my son's house.  Someone else might be able to find it before I get a chance to.

Comment: Good point DVK, Bill if you could find that source, I'd be most appreciative.